# Average of decimal digits

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, decimal-expansion

I define the function $d_{\mathrm{avg}} : [0, 1]\to [0, 1]$ such that for $0.x_1x_2x_3\cdots$ the decimal expansion of $x$ (defined such that $\nexists N : x_k = 9$ for all $k \geq N$), $$d_{\mathrm{avg}} : x\mapsto \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i$$ How would I show that the set $\{x : d_{\mathrm{avg}}(x)\text{ does not exist}\}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$? It's clear to me that the set is uncountable.

Comment: Every intervals contains rational number whose decimal expansion is either finite or periodic.

Comment: Alright, so it follows pretty much trivially from the density of the rationals in the reals. I kept trying to formulate some sort of constructive proof... should have taken the simpler way out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since almost all numbers are normal,
$d_{avg}(x)
=4.5
$
for almost all $x$.

Therefore
the set of all $x$
for which
$d_{avg}(x)
$
does not exist
has measure zero.

Comment: Thanks! Proving that almost all numbers are normal seems a little heavy-handed in this case, but it definitely does the trick.